# Determining Height of sign based on max vieweing angle being 35 feet away

Tags: calculus

So I am running into an issue with trying to figure this out.  Here is the question:

```
Suppose I’m hanging a sign over the road
and the bottom must be 20 feet off the ground. I want the location of
the maximum viewing angle to be 35 feet away. How tall should I make
the sign?
```

So from what I understand I am looking for to solve arctan(alpha) = 20+y/35, but when I solve this, it ends up being infinity. Since the height cannot be infinity I must be doing something wrong, as this makes no sense, but based on what I have read and learned this seems like he correct formula to use since "x" is the denominator and is the distance between the person standing and the sign, and we are adding 20 and y(the unknown additonal height of the sign) and taking the arctan of that over "x" to determine the height.  I am sorry for asking what must be a very basic question, but in most of the examples I see, you are given the 2 heights and solve for x, not the distance of the maximum viewing angle and asked to solve for the height(y in my example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, so I'll make some guesses.

Let $P$ be the top of the sign, $Q$ the bottom, and $R$ the point below the sign on the road.  Of course $QR=20$ and you are interested in $PQ$.

Say you are standing at a distance $x$ away from $R$.  The angle from which you view the sign is $$f(x)=\arctan \frac {PQ+20}x-\arctan \frac {20}x$$

When is that a maximum?

Well, a little effort gives us $$f'(x)= \frac {PQ (400 + 20 PQ - x^2)}{
(400 + x^2) (400 + 40 PQ + PQ^2 + x^2)}$$

We want to solve $$f'(x)=0\implies x=\sqrt {400+20PQ}$$

As we are told that the max occurs at $x=35$ we get $$\sqrt {400+20PQ}=35\implies PQ=41.25$$

Does this seem like what you had in mind?  Mind you, it seems like a rather big sign.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the correct way to go about it...I believe the issue I was having was that I was pluging in 35 for x on the initial equation isntead of leaving it out til the end